# Minimum angular size galaxy

Tags: cosmology, galaxies

I've heard a mention in a lecture that galaxies have a Minimum angular size. Naively, the angular size should drop as $1/d^2$. The effect is supposed to stem from the expansion of the universe.

What is the reason for this effect?

Comment: This page https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March02/Sahni/Sahni4_5.html describes a cosmological model in which galaxies have a *minimum* angular size. This seems more plausible than a *maximum* angular size.

Comment: Thanks! ofcourse, it was a mistake...